# UIView overlay on collectionViewController with NavBar and TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to create a UIView overlay that says "Loading data.." on my second TabBarController that doesn't cover my navigationBar and TabBar.

I currently have this as my code

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.view.frame];

overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
overlayView.alpha = 0.4;
overlayView.tag = 88;

UILabel *message = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.view.frame];
[message setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20.0f]];
message.text = @"Loading data...";
message.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
message.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
message.tag = 99;

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlayView];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:message];
```

Currently the message is working good, but the UIView overlay is covering my TabBar? Can you help me fix this?

**To clear it up :** I want to show a UIView overlay programmatically that doesn't cover up the navBar and the tabBar.

Thanks and cheers!

Comment: do you want an black overlay which does not cover navigation and tab bar?

Comment: Exactly @HirenPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your view on `ViewController` so it will not cover both `NavigationBar` and `TabBar`.

```
[self.view addSubview:overlayView];
[self.view addSubview:message];
```

Set frame as per your current view.

Hope this will help to overlay on full screen.

Comment: Hi, I'm asking the reverse of this, I don't want my NavigationBar and TabBar to be covered..

Comment: So for that you have to add it into your view Controller.